# Date handling in a "real time" system

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I've a toy (Java) project which aims to work as a server between signal providers, data provider and signal executors. This system receives messages of the following format from the data provider:

EURUSD@11214,11216,11213,11215,1,03/22/2016_17:36:01

My question is about the date: creating a new java util Date at every message is going to cause lots of garbage and I'd like to avoid that. I could store the info in an int array (year, month, day, hours, etc), but I'd lose many of the benefits of Date, i.e. ease of comparing two instances. What would you do?

Please avoid replies like "Premature optimisation" or "Objects creation is cheap in Java".

Comment: This is a very broad question, I'm not sure that SO is really the place for it. Maybe programmers.stackexchange would be a better place for it?

Comment: @beresfordt: P.SE is not for very broad questions either

Comment: Moderators feel free to close the question if not suited for SO.

Comment: I wouldn't bother about performance while it is not a problem, especially when it is a toy project. Because usually actual performance drainer and expected one are not the same thing.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not a big user of P.SE. Does this question not fit there under the banner of software design/methodologies, in particular how to handle Date with minimal garbage being created?

Comment: "Please avoid replies like "Premature optimisation" or "Objects creation is cheap in Java"." - when the situation that you explained is really a bottleneck, then you'll have to solve this problem, considering all the specific usages of `Date` your project have. So the solution will be exclusively designed for your particular use-case. and thus these answers are perfectly valid, because they really answer your broad question.

Comment: @user3707125 No they are not. Performances are part of the validity of the project and being told "premature optimisation" is neither helpful nor original. I'm after solutions like caches or external libraries which have dates that are not immutable, or any other helpful advice.

Comment: @IvanValeriani, have you tested it? Are you already using Netty as a web-server? Because other web-servers will create a lot more garbage per request than a tiny `Date` instance.

Comment: @user3707125 Thanks for your advice. When I'll decide to use a web server, I'll give Netty a go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store date in a plain `long` (number of milliseconds from Epoch).

Convert it to year/month/day and back using a single instance of [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
(or `ThreadLocal<Calendar>` in mutithreaded environment).

Comment: To do so, I have to parse the string into a date. So i get one date object for each message I receive. Ideally I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @IvanValeriani You can reuse `Calendar` instance for parsing.